# How to input a dropdown or is it possible to input a dropdown within a listview builder using maps from an other class file?

Tags: flutter, listview, drop-down-menu, maps, dropdown

I am creating an order application for a cafe and on this I have a list of the cafes items outside of the main class as its own file that I created using maps and in the main dart I have already called to the map class outside of the file and put it into a listview builder however I want there to be dropdowns too within the main page. I want the listviewer and the dropdownbuttons to be connected but I don't know if I can use the maps within the dropdown or do I have to turn them into lists and what not. Also if we can used maps within the dropdownbuttons how do we define it as an "items" if the dropdownbutton.

here is my map file

```
class Menu {

  Menu();
  Menu.s(this._sandwichMap);
  Menu.b(this._burgerMap);
  Menu.o(this._otherItemsMap);
  Menu.q(this._sidesMap);
  Menu.p(this._pizzaMap);


  Map<String, double> _sandwichMap = {
    "Veggie Melt": 4.50,
    "Crispy Chicken Wrap": 6.95,
    "Italian Meatball Sub": 6.99,
    "Chicken Parm Grinder": 6.59,
    "Grill Cheese": 3.59,
    "Grilled Ham & Cheese": 4.59,
    "Bacon Bagel Melt": 5.29};

  Map<String, double> getSandwichMap() {
    return this._sandwichMap;
  }

  //check burger prices again
  Map<String, double> _burgerMap = {
    "Veggie Burger": 4.99,
    "The Quantum Burger": 7.25,
    "Cafe Melt": 6.59,
    "The Bull Rider": 5.79,
    "Double Cheese Burger": 5.89,
    "Hamburger": 3.99};

  Map<String, double> getBurgerMap() {
    return this._burgerMap;
  }

  Map<String, double> _otherItemsMap = {
    "Chicken Quesadilla": 6.79,
    "Cheese Quesadilla": 6.29,
    "Chicken Strips": 4.99,
    "Popcorn Chicken": 4.59,
    "Jalapeno Poppers": 3.49};

  Map<String, double> getOtherItemsMap() {
    return this._otherItemsMap;
  }
  Map<String, double> _sidesMap = {
    "French Fries": 3.29,
    "Onion Rings": 4.79,
    "Jalapeno Cheese Curds": 4.99,
    "Tater Tots": 3.19,
    "Pretzel Bites": 4.59,
    "Nachos & Cheese": 3.50};

  Map<String, double> getSidesMap() {
    return this._sidesMap;
  }
  Map<String, double> _pizzaMap = {
    "7-inch Cheese": 4.59,
    "7-inc with topping": 4.99};


  Map<String, double> getPizzaMap() {
    return this._pizzaMap;
  }
}
```

And here is my main file with the dropdowns

```
 import 'dart:core';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'maps.dart';

//var menu = Menu();


void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  //Always use Stateless first then use stateful or stateless widgets afterward
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //only used at the beginning of the program
      title: 'The Cafe',
      //just a title to the app it does not show for there is nothing telling it to show on the screen
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //takes out the ribbon at the top right corner of the screen and app
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          fontFamily: 'georgia',
          textTheme: TextTheme(headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 100))
        //controls the color of the very top part of the application
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
      //used to connect the Stateless widget to the Stateful widget below
    );
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
}
// do not forget the } prior to this comment  if you do it will result in error and the program does not known why either

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {


  var menu = Menu();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('The Campus Cafe'),
        //where the main title is computed to be shown on the screen
        centerTitle: true,
        //centers the title
      ),
      body: Center(
        //This is Header that is after the main Title
        child: Column(

            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[

              //Header Container
              Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/campus-cafe-logo-350sidebar.png',)
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Our Menu", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    String key = menu.getSandwichMap().keys.elementAt(index);
                    List<String> key1 = menu.getSandwichMap().keys.toList();
                    //List<double> key2 = menu.getSandwichMap().values.toList();
                  return DropdownButton(
                    value: key[index],
                    items: key,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                    key = value;
                    setState(() {});
                    },
                              hint: Text('Sandwich'),
                              );
                  return DropdownButton(items: [],

                  );
                              }),

                ),

            ]

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

If more information is needed on how I want my dropdowns too look I want them too look like the file below with just the listview.builder but I want that information to be within a dropdown if possible

```
    import 'dart:core';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'maps.dart';

//var menu = Menu();


void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  //Always use Stateless first then use stateful or stateless widgets afterward
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //only used at the beginning of the program
      title: 'The Cafe',
      //just a title to the app it does not show for there is nothing telling it to show on the screen
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //takes out the ribbon at the top right corner of the screen and app
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          fontFamily: 'georgia',
          textTheme: TextTheme(headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 100))
        //controls the color of the very top part of the application
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
      //used to connect the Stateless widget to the Stateful widget below
    );
  }
}

  class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
  }
// do not forget the } prior to this comment  if you do it will result in error and the program does not known why either

  class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {


    var menu = Menu();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('The Campus Cafe'),
          //where the main title is computed to be shown on the screen
          centerTitle: true,
          //centers the title
        ),
        body: Center(
          //This is Header that is after the main Title
          child: Column(

              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[

                //Header Container
                Expanded(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/campus-cafe-logo-350sidebar.png',)
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Our Menu", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: menu.getSandwichMap().length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      String key = menu.getSandwichMap().keys.elementAt(index);
                      return new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //DropdownButton<String>(
                            //isExpanded: true;
                            //items: menu.getSandwichMap();
                          new ListTile(
                            title: new Text("$key"),
                            subtitle: new Text("${menu.getSandwichMap()[key]}"),
                          ),
                          new Divider(
                            height: 2.0,
                          ),
                         // ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ]

          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: it's the basic of an OOP approach, you should use other classes to store and manipulate data, just check any state management tutorial follow along for someday

Answer (score 0):

It is not that difficult to build a dropdown field from your map  values.

Basically the idea is you need to get a  `List<String>` first. Then, your life will be much easier. How you want to get there, is up to you.

I have created a DartPad example using your values. Try have a look there.

https://dartpad.dev/93b680c13c57e7a8faff99116793cd3f

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  
  final List<String> sandwichItems = sandwichMap.keys.toList();
  String dropdownValue;
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return 
      Container(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue ?? sandwichItems[0],
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: sandwichItems.map((e){
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: e,
          child: Text(e),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
    );
  }
}


Map<String, double> sandwichMap = {
    "Veggie Melt": 4.50,
    "Crispy Chicken Wrap": 6.95,
    "Italian Meatball Sub": 6.99,
    "Chicken Parm Grinder": 6.59,
    "Grill Cheese": 3.59,
    "Grilled Ham & Cheese": 4.59,
    "Bacon Bagel Melt": 5.29};
```